# Trying to Parse SOAP Response in Python

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I'm struggling to find a way to parse the data that I'm getting back from a SOAP response. I'm only familiar with Python (v3.4), but relatively new to it. I'm using suds-jurko to pull the data from a 3rd party SOAP server. The response comes back in the form of "ArrayOfXmlNode". I've tried using ElementTree in different ways to parse the data, but I either get no information or I get "TypeError: invalid file: (ArrayOfXmlNode)" errors. Googling how to handle the ArrayOfXMLNode type response has gotten me nowhere.

The first part of the SOAP response is:

```
(ArrayOfXmlNode){
   XmlNode[] = 
      (XmlNode){
         Hl = 
            (Hl){
               ID = "22437790"
               Name = "Cameron"
               SpeciesID = "1"
               Sex = "Male"
               PrimaryBreed = "German Shepherd"
               SecondaryBreed = "Mix"
               SN = ""
               Age = "35"
               OnHold = "No"
               Location = "Foster Home"
               BehaviorResult = ""
               Photo = "http://sms.petpoint.com/sms/photos/615/123.jpg"
            }
      },
```

I've tried iterating through the data with code similar to:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://qag.petpoint.com/webservices/AdoptableSearch.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(url)


result = client.service.adoptableSearchExtended('nunya', 0, 'A', 'All', 'N')

tree = result[0]

for node in tree:
    pet_info = []
    pet_info.extend(node)    

print(pet_info)
```

The code above gives me the entire response in "result[0]". Below that I try to create a list from the data, but only get very last node (node being 1 set of information from ID to Photo). Attempts to modify this approach gives me either everything, nothing, or only the last node.

So then I tried to make use of ElementTree with simple code to test it out, but only get the "invalid file" errors.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://qag.petpoint.com/webservices/AdoptableSearch.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(url)


result = client.service.adoptableSearchExtended('nunya', 0, 'A', 'All', 'N')

pet_info = ET.parse(result)
print(pet_info)
```

The result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Eclipse Workspace\KivyTest\src\root\nested\Parse.py", line 11, in <module>
    pet_info = ET.parse(result)
  File "D:\Programs\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1186, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "D:\Programs\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
TypeError: invalid file: (ArrayOfXmlNode){
   XmlNode[] = 
      (XmlNode){
         Hl = 
            (Hl){
               ID = "20840097"
               Name = "Daisy"
               SpeciesID = "1"
               Sex = "Female"
               PrimaryBreed = "Terrier, Pit Bull"
               SecondaryBreed = ""
               SN = ""
               Age = "42"
               OnHold = "No"
               Location = "Dog Adoption"
               BehaviorResult = ""
               Photo = "http://sms.petpoint.com/sms/photos/615/40f428de-c015-4334-9101-89c707383817.jpg"
            }
      },
```

Can someone get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem parsing data from a web service using Python 3.4 and suds-jurko.  I was able to solve the issue using the code in this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844428/5874347.  I used the fastest_object_to_dict function to convert the web service response into a dictionary.  From there you can parse the data ...

1. Add the fastest_object_to_dict function to the top of your file
2. Make your web service call
3. Create a new variable to save the dictionary response to

   ```
   result = client.service.adoptableSearchExtended('nunya', 0, 'A', 'All', 'N') 
   ParsedResponse = fastest_object_to_dict(result)
   ```
4. Your data will now be in the form of a dictionary, you can parse the dictionary on the python side as needed or send it back to your ajax call via json, and parse it with javascript.
   To send it back as json

   ```
   import json
   import sys
   sys.stdout.write("content-type: text/json\r\n\r\n") 
   sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(ParsedReponse))
   ```

Comment: That would have been easier than what I ended up doing. I used a series of ElementTree replace statements to convert the SOAP response into an xml format. From the xml I am able to iterate and find the data associated with each xml tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
result[0][0]
```

which will give you the first element of the array (ArrayOfXmlNode).
Similarly, try this:

```
result[0][1][2]
```

which will give you the third element of element result[0][1].

Hopefully, this offers an alternative solution.

Comment: Ian, i've been at it for a few hours and finally decided to try this solution (i have a slightly different question to the one asked) you sorted me out and so simply... so much better - thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python, you can parse this result JSON from a XML result.
But your SOAP result needs to be a XML output, you can use the retxml=True on suds library.

I needed this result as a JSON output as well, and I ended up solving this way:

```
import xmltodict

# Parse the XML result into dict
data_dict = xmltodict.parse(soap_response)

# Dump the dict result into a JSON result
json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
    
# Load the JSON string result
json = json.loads(json_data)
```